# How to Find Element by Link Text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I've few web links please let me know how I can visit their contact pages i've tried using but not working

`contact_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Contact')`

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"contact")]')
```

Every web page have different classes and different attributes so it is possible to do..

thanks

Comment: `driverr.find_element_by_xpath["//a[contains(text(),contact')]"]` this code will never work:)
Please provide part of html code you want to use

Comment: I've multiple websites so I've the only solution if link_text work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one on each page (each site homepage)
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"contact")]').click()`

Comment: oh... yeap) `click()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Contact").click()
```